# bound the norm of the sum of the difference between the orthogonal projection of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, projection

Let $P_k$ define an orthogonal projection on a ball of radius of $k$, and $x_i$, $y_i$ are two vectors. Now, I would like to bound:
\begin{equation}
 ||\sum_{i=1}^n P_k(x_i) - P_k(y_i)||^2 
\end{equation}

I know that I can bound it using Cauchy-schwarz inequality and VI such that:
\begin{equation}
||\sum_{i=1}^n P_k(x_i) - P_k(y_k)||^2 \leq n\sum_{i=1}^n||P_k(x_i) - P_k(y_i)||^2 \leq n\sum_{i=1}^n ||x_i - y_i||^2 
\end{equation}

However, I wonder if I can get a bound, e.g., $||\sum_{i=1}^n x_i-y_i||^2$.

Comment: Can you explain more what $P_k$ is? Is it an orthogonal projection (in the linear algebra sense), restricted to a ball? (If so, mentioning the ball is unnecessary.) Is it a map which acts as the identity on the ball, and normalizes other vectors to the surface of the ball (assuming the ball's center is the origin)?

Comment: Also I don't understand why you're putting $n$ in front of the sum. My guess is you are incorrectly combining the triangle inequality with the relation $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\le n\max_i a_i$ (when summands are nonnegative). // Addendum: in your first line, you mean $x,y$ are two vectors (so $x_i,y_i$ refer to their components). And what does VI stand for again?

Comment: Sure. $P_k$ is a projection such that $||x_i|| \leq k$, basically if the norm of the vector is larger than $k$, I normalize it such that $||x_i|| = k$. Otherwise, it's just identity mapping. There is a $n$ in front of the $L_2$ norm is because $||\sum_{i=1}^n a_i||^2 \leq n\sum_{i=1}^n ||a_i||^2$, e.g., $(a+b)^2 \leq 2(a^2+b^2)$. VI represents variational inequality

Comment: Ah, I see. $P_k(x)=kx/\|x\|$ is retraction onto a "sphere," not a "ball," to clarify. Also that $n$ in front of the sum seems pointless. The triangle inequality already yields $\|\sum a_i\|^2\le\sum\| a_i\|^2$; multiplying the RHS by $n\ge1$ just makes the upper bound unnecessarily loose (*extremely* loose, and thus, likely throws away its usefulness). It's like saying Alice is shorter than the Eiffel Tower instead of saying Alice is shorter than Bob; the latter conveys potentially useful information where the former doesn't.

Comment: I am also questioning if I understand the summation in the first place. You said there are only two vectors, so how are you summing over $n$ terms? Are there actually $2n$ different vectors $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, $y_1,\cdots,y_n$? Or are $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, $y=(y_1,\cdots,y_n)$ two vectors and the $x_i,y_i$ are their components? If the latter, how are we interpreting $P_k(x_i)$ and $P_k(y_i)$ given $x_i,y_i$ are scalar values and the domain of $P_k$ consists of vectors?

Comment: Thanks! Ok, thanks for pointing out the mistake regarding the ball. I agree with your example of the Eiffel Tower. However, $||\sum a_i||^2 \leq \sum ||a_i||^2$ doesn't necessarily hold. For example, if $a_1=[0, 1], a_2=[2, 3]$ Then $||\sum a_i||^2 = 20$. However, $\sum||a_i||^2 = 14$ and $20 > 14$. And $x_i, y_i$ are vectors, $i$ can simply be the sample index or time index.

Comment: Ah, of course - for some reason my brain inserted squares in the triangle inequality! I will just assume there are $2n$ different vectors.